# Haproxy in docker container unstable

Tags: docker, haproxy

HI i am facing issue with haproxy in docker container. every time when i build my docker container for HA it will work fine, but after sometime it will stop working by giving below error.

Error:-

```
.<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
```

My docker file :-

```
FROM centos
ENV container docker
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum install -y passwd
RUN echo root | passwd --stdin root
RUN yum -y swap -- remove fakesystemd -- install systemd systemd-libs
RUN yum install -y net-tools
RUN yum install -y lsof
EXPOSE 80
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

My haproxy file :-

```
global

log         127.0.0.1 local2
chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn     4000
user        haproxy
group       haproxy
daemon

stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
mode                    http
log                     global
option                  httplog
option                  dontlognull
option http-server-close
option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
option                  redispatch
retries                 3
timeout http-request    10s
timeout queue           1m
timeout connect         10s
timeout client          1m
timeout server          1m
timeout http-keep-alive 10s
timeout check           10s
maxconn                 3000


frontend  main *:80
default_backend             app


backend app
balance roundrobin
server  www1 172.17.0.3:80 check
server  www2 172.17.0.4:80 check
```

Docker Run :-

```
docker run --privileged -ti -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro sb/ha
```

I have two appache servers, both are in docker with ip 172.17.0.3 and 172.17.0.4. I am not sure why its unstable, Please help check and suggest me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker does not provide any warranty on the IP of your container. If for any reason your containers crash or restart, their IP will change so you HAProxy config becomes obsolete and needs to be updated.

You can take a look at tutum's haproxy image that dynamically looks up container's addresses: https://github.com/tutumcloud/haproxy

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I always take care of ip's of my apache web server's as well as HAproxy server.